# Weakenings of the Bounded Approximation Property

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space, and let $F(X)$ be the finite-rank operators on $X$.

Then $X$ has the $\lambda$-BAP if there exists a net  $(S_i)_i$ in $F(X)$ with $\sup_i\|S_i\|\leq\lambda$ such that $S_i\to\mathrm{id}_X$ pointwise, that is, $\|S_i(x)-x\|\to 0$ for every $x\in X$.

What is the connection to the following variants of this property: (Explanation of terminology below.)

(1) There exists a net $(S_i)_i$ in $F(X)$ with $\sup_i\|S_i\|\leq\lambda$ such that $S_i\to\mathrm{id}_X$ in point-weak-topology, that is, $S_i(x)$ converges weakly to $x$ for every $x\in X$.

(2) There exists a net $(S_i)_i$ in $F(X)$ with $\sup_i\|S_i\|\leq\lambda$ such that $S_i\to\mathrm{id}_X$ in the weak*-topology of $B(X)\subset B(X,X^{**})$.

(2') There exists a net $(S_i)_i$ in $F(X,X^{**})$ with $\sup_i\|S_i\|\leq\lambda$ such that $S_i\to\mathrm{id}_X$ in the weak*-topology of $B(X,X^{**})$.

(3) For every $S$ in the unit ball of $B(X,X^{**})$, there exists a net $(S_i)_i$ in $B(X)$ with $\sup_i\|S_i\|\leq\lambda$ such that $S_i\to S$ weak*.

We have $\lambda$-BAP $\Rightarrow$ (1) $\Rightarrow$ (2) $\Rightarrow$ (2') $\Rightarrow$ (3).

> Question: Which of these arrows can be reversed?

Also, I would be interested to know if these properties (in case they are not equivalent to the BAP) have been considered in the literature before.

I think (2) $\Leftarrow$ (2') should be a direct consequence of the "Principle of local reflexivity". I also suspect that one could try to show $\lambda$-BAP $\Leftarrow$ (1) by passing to convex combinations of operators $S_i$ satisfying (1).

Note that (2) can be rephrases as: "The subspace $F(X)\subset B(X,X^{**})$ is $\lambda$-norming.", and similarly for (2') and (3). Note that every reflexive space satisfies (3), but not all reflexive spaces have the $\lambda$-BAP.

*Terminology:*

We let $B(X,Y)$ denote the space of bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$.
We give $B(X,X^{**})$ the natural weak*-topology coming from the identification $B(X,X^{**})=(X\hat{\otimes}X^*)^*$. The natural embedding of $B(X)$ in $B(X,X^{**})$ sends an operator $a\colon X\to X$ to the operator $\kappa_X\circ a\colon X\to X^{**}$, where $\kappa_X\colon X\to X^{**}$ is the embedding of $X$ into its bidual.

A subspace $M$ of $X^*$ is *$\lambda$-norming* if $\|x\|\leq\lambda\sup\{|f(x)| : f\in M, \|f\|\leq 1\}$ for every $x\in X$, which is equivalent to the condition that the unit ball of $X^*$ is contained in the weak*-closure of the ball of radius $\lambda$ in $M$.

The usual definition of the *$\lambda$-Bounded Approximation Property* ($\lambda$-BAP) is: There exists a net $(S_i)_i$ in $F(X)$ with $\sup_i\|S_i\|\leq\lambda$ and such that $S_i\to\mathrm{id}_X$ uniformly on compact subsets, that is, for every compact subset $K\subset X$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $i$ such that $\|S_i(x)-x\|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in K$.
This is equivalent to the above e.g. by Proposition 4.3, p.73, in Ryan: "Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces".

Comment: (1), (2), and (2)' are equivalent to the $\lambda$-BAP for the reasons you suggest. It is a good exercise to work this out if you are interested in the topic. (3) likely does not imply the others, but I don't have time to think about it now.  Previous MO postings on the AP might have something relevant for that. Or maybe my paper with Oikhberg essentially contains an example--have you looked at that paper?

Comment: @BillJohnson I am probably missing something (tiredness and writing homework solutions and wine) but wouldn't any reflexive $X$ satisfy (3) for trivial reasons? In which case we just need a reflexive $X$ without AP, and then one can use the known examples of subspaces of $\ell_p$, $1<p<2$, that don't have AP

Comment: @BillJohnson Thank you. To summarize, $X$ has the BAP iff there is a uniformly bounded net of finite-rank operators $X^*\to X^*$ that converges to the identity on $X^*$ in point-weak*-topology. However, considering the same for the point-weak-topology is equivalent to the BAP for $X*$ (which implies the BAP for $X$, but not conversely.)

Comment: @YemonChoi Thank you. I agree that every reflexive space without AP shows that (3) does not imply the other (equivalent) properties.

Comment: Yes, of course, Yemon. I'll blame it on wine.  :)